How to turn off appending of letters to years in biblatex?
I have the following customized biblatex setup to create two separate bibliographies, one for primary literature, in which the titles of classical Sanskrit work will be linked usually to editions, being sorted according the order of the Sanskrit alphabet, and one for secondary publications, i.e., modern works, in which a publication would be listed by author (or editor or translator) and year. The same publication might be referred to in both ways, which is where trouble starts. In the following, I want the Yogabhāṣya, a classical text, to appear in my primary bibliography, and its standard edition to also appear in my secondary bibliography. Now, for some reason, they are counted as two different items, leading to the year in the secondary bibliography to be appended with an a, i.e. 1904a instead of simply 1904. Is there an easy way to suppress the appending of letters to specific bibliography items, or, even better, a more elegant solution which avoids the problem from occurring?
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newcommand{\skti}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sktt}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}\index{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}{}}}
\newcommand{\sktw}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}\index{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}{}}}
\newcommand{\sktn}[1]{\textsanskrit{#1}\index{\textsanskrit{#1}{}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,%
indexing=true,%
noibid%
]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Yogabhāṣya,
title = {\textsanskrit{Yogabhāṣya}},
related = {Agase1904},
relatedoptions = {skipbib=true},
keywords = {pri},
entrysubtype = {classical},
options = {useauthor=false,useeditor=false},
}

@book{Agase1904,
title = {\textsanskrit{Vācaspatimiśraviracitaṭīkāsaṃvalitavyāsabhāṣyasametāni Pātañjalayogasūtrāṇi tathā Bhojadevaviracitarājamārtaṇḍābhidhavṛttisametāni Pātañjalayogasūtrāṇi}},
editor = {Kāśinātha Śāstrī Āgāśe},
year = {1904},
location = {Pune},
series = {Ānandāśrama},
number = {47},
relatedoptions = {usetranslator=false,useeditor=false,skipbib=true,clearfield{title}},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDatafieldSet{settitles}{
\member[field=title]
\member[field=booktitle]
\member[field=eventtitle]
\member[field=issuetitle]
\member[field=journaltitle]
\member[field=maintitle]
\member[field=origtitle]
\member[field=sortkey]
}
\DeclareSortTranslit{
\translit{settitles}{iast}{devanagari}
}


\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\newbibmacro*{pri:titleofauthor}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}
       {\ifbibliography
         {\printfield{title}%
          \ifnameundef{author}
            {}
            {\setunit*{\addspace}%
             \bibstring{of}%
             \setunit*{\addspace}%
             \printnames{author}%
             \clearname{author}}%
          \clearfield{title}}
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{title}}%
          \ifnameundef{labelname}
            {}
            {}%
          \clearfield{labeltitle}%
          \clearname{labelname}}}
       {}}
    {}}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\usebibmacro{pri:titleofauthor}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{bibindex}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibindex}\usebibmacro{pri:titleofauthor}}
  {}
  {}



\begin{document}
\nocite{Agase1904}
\nocite{Yogabhāṣya}
\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, notkeyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}


Try dataonly=true, instead of only skipbib=true, in relatedoptions, where dataonly is an abbreviation for uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, skipbib, skipbiblist and skiplab (the skiplab is what we need here, it makes sure the entry is not counted for uniqueness considerations).
The biblatex-chicago manual explains (§5.2.1 Fields for Related Entries, p. 149 in v2.3b 2024-04-15)

[relatedoptions]
This field will, I should expect, only be needed very rarely. If you want to set entry-level options for a related entry this is where you can do it, though please remember one important detail. By default, Biber sets this option to dataonly, which among other things prevents the related entry from appearing separately in the list of references, assuming
you don’t specifically cite it elsewhere. If you use the field yourself, then you’ll need to
include dataonly as one of the options therein to maintain this effect. Of course, it may
be you don’t want all the effects of dataonly, so you can tailor it however you wish.

From the MWE I then get
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\sanskritfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newcommand{\skti}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sktt}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}\index{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}{}}}
\newcommand{\sktw}[1]{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}\index{\emph{\textsanskrit{#1}}{}}}
\newcommand{\sktn}[1]{\textsanskrit{#1}\index{\textsanskrit{#1}{}}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,%
indexing=true,%
noibid%
]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Yogabhāṣya,
title = {\textsanskrit{Yogabhāṣya}},
related = {Agase1904},
relatedoptions = {dataonly=true},
keywords = {pri},
entrysubtype = {classical},
options = {useauthor=false,useeditor=false},
}
@book{Agase1904,
title = {\textsanskrit{Vācaspatimiśraviracitaṭīkāsaṃvalitavyāsabhāṣyasametāni Pātañjalayogasūtrāṇi tathā Bhojadevaviracitarājamārtaṇḍābhidhavṛttisametāni Pātañjalayogasūtrāṇi}},
editor = {Kāśinātha Śāstrī Āgāśe},
year = {1904},
location = {Pune},
series = {Ānandāśrama},
number = {47},
relatedoptions = {usetranslator=false,useeditor=false,dataonly=true,clearfield{title}},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDatafieldSet{settitles}{
\member[field=title]
\member[field=booktitle]
\member[field=eventtitle]
\member[field=issuetitle]
\member[field=journaltitle]
\member[field=maintitle]
\member[field=origtitle]
\member[field=sortkey]
}
\DeclareSortTranslit{
\translit{settitles}{iast}{devanagari}
}


\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}\isdot}
\newbibmacro*{pri:titleofauthor}{%
  \ifentrytype{misc}
    {\iffieldequalstr{entrysubtype}{classical}
       {\ifbibliography
         {\printfield{title}%
          \ifnameundef{author}
            {}
            {\setunit*{\addspace}%
             \bibstring{of}%
             \setunit*{\addspace}%
             \printnames{author}%
             \clearname{author}}%
          \clearfield{title}}
         {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{title}}%
          \ifnameundef{labelname}
            {}
            {}%
          \clearfield{labeltitle}%
          \clearname{labelname}}}
       {}}
    {}}
\xpretobibmacro{cite}
  {\usebibmacro{pri:titleofauthor}}
  {}
  {}
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{bibindex}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibindex}\usebibmacro{pri:titleofauthor}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\cite{Agase1904}
\cite{Yogabhāṣya}
\printbibliography[title=Primary Sources, keyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[title=Secondary Sources, notkeyword=pri,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}


